# Does a second join ever improve query performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I found a legacy sproc in our system that includes a redundant second join for "performance reasons."

[image]
But if I look at the query execution plan it appears the second join actually increases the query cost by ~30%.

[image]

Does a second join ever improve performance? What might the original author been thinking of when he or she added the second join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A second join can improve performance.  Join's can be used for filtering, which reduces the number of rows.

This would be particularly true if the join keys are indexed, so the filtering can take place very quickly.

The reduced result set can also speed aggregations and sorting.

If the result sets are exactly the same, the second join might improve performance by enabling a better execution plan.  However, there may be other ways to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

If the additional table being joined to contained an index that could be used in the query, while the other tables did not... then you might get a performance boost by virtue of being able to use the index instead of a full scan.

My guess is that you'd be better off just adding the index to one of the existing tables and avoiding the extra join, but I guess it would depend on the specific situation?

That's the only benefit I can think of (assuming you don't actually need to select any of the fields)!